# What is the correct way to ask for a user's permission to enable web push notifications?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker, web-push, web-notifications

I currently learning about service workers, and in particular subscribing a user to push notifications. I've worked through the [Web Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user) *Guide* and [Adding Push Notifications to a Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/) *Code Lab* that Google publishes - but I'm seeing two different ways of asking for a user's permission.

The guide asks using the `Notification` interface of the Notifications API [like this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user#requesting_permission) and then calls `subscribe()` based on the return value of `.requestPermission()`:

```
function askPermission() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const permissionResult = Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
      resolve(result);
    });

    if (permissionResult) {
      permissionResult.then(resolve, reject);
    }
  })
  .then(function(permissionResult) {
    if (permissionResult !== 'granted') {
      throw new Error('We weren\'t granted permission.');
    }
  });
}
```

And the Code Lab asks by only calling `.subscribe()` (which will bring up the notification prompt) directly on the service worker registration's `PushManager` [like this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/#subscribe_the_user):

```
function subscribeUser() {
  const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
  swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
  })
  .then(function(subscription) {
    console.log('User is subscribed.');

    updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);

    isSubscribed = true;

    updateBtn();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
    updateBtn();
  });
}
```

I've looked through the mozilla docs for [`PushManager.subscribe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager/subscribe) and [`Notification.requestPermission()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission) but am **struggling to identify the trade-offs of each of Google's flows and in particular whether or not the extra step of `Notification.requestPermission(..)` is necessary**.

It's worth noting that `.subscribe()` is currently marked as an experimental feature where-as `.requestPermission()` is not.

Answer (score 7):

As with most times I end up posting on Stack Overflow, I found the answer by re-looking through everything. In fact, the [Guide I referenced above answers this question directly](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user#permissions_and_subscribe):

> There is one side effect of calling subscribe(). If your web app doesn't have permissions for showing notifications at the time of calling subscribe(), the browser will request the permissions for you. This is useful if your UI works with this flow, but if you want more control (and I think most developers will), stick to the Notification.requestPermission() API that we used earlier.